# How to pass % as param in windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, bash-scripting

I'm trying to login to a server where my password contains `%` char.

this is what I'm trying to execute via `myscript.bat` which has a line `net.exe use x: \\SERVER_IP\C$ /user:%USERNAME% n%5Ar!33`
while I execute it, it became `n5Ar!33` which leads to an auth failure.

If I run the command directly, It's working fine as the direct command not skipping `%` character.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I've changed `%` with `%%` and it's working like a charm.

Comment: @harrymc where is the duplicate link dear? Please let me know so that I can update.

BTW, I answered my question after I resolve my issue.